# How to conditionally load a package only if shell-escape (write18) is passed

Tags: conditionals, shell-escape

The package `gitver` requires `-shell-escape` to fetch git metadata from the manuscript's git repository on the local filesystem.

However, it is needless to pass the `shell-escape` flag when compiling the source outside of a `git`VCS repo (such as on my advisor's machine). It is tedious to comment-out and comment-in this line appropriately. It is also hard to change other collaborator's (good) habits of not compiling with `-shell-escape` enabled.  However, `gitver` complains loudly and errors out/halts if shell-escape is not detected.

Hence, can I change my preamble in such a way that a generic source line (not just to loading `gitver` package, but the same argument applies to `minted` and other generic latex commands) is executed only when compiled with shell-escape?

Minimal conceptual example:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%% Somehow detect shell-escape here
  \usepackage{gitver} % <-- load only if compiled with shell-escape 
%%% end of test

\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the given problem you may want to have a look at `gitinfo2` instead of `gitver` since `gitinfo2` doesn’t require shell-escape (I think).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

expl3 has a test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\csname sys_if_shell_unrestricted:T\endcsname{\usepackage{gitver}} 
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought I had added this to shellescape package (or at least a common name for a number to test) but apparently not:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I checked shellesc first ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer perfect. Works like a charm. Upvoted & accepted.

Comment: Imho you should make a feature request for the package. It should have a "warn" mode and quit cleanly if shell-escape is not enabled. As you said: it is a pain if such packages then errors.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe `pdftexcmds`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pdftexcmds` and define a three-branch test:

```latex
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ShellEscapeURN}[3]{%
  \ifcase\pdf@shellescape
    \expandafter\@firstofthree  % 0 = no shell escape
  \or
    \expandafter\@secondofthree % 1 = unrestricted
  \or
    \expandafter\@thirdofthree  % 2 = restricted
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofthree
  \fi
  {#3}{#1}{#2}%
}
\providecommand{\@firstofthree}[3]{#1}
\providecommand{\@secondofthree}[3]{#2}
\providecommand{\@thirdofthree}[3]{#3}
\makeatother
```

The three arguments are “code for Unrestricted shell escape”, “code for Restricted shell escape” and “code for No shell escape” respectively.

In your case,

```
\ShellEscapeURN{\usepackage{gitver}}{}{}
```

It might be more convenient to use `expl3` so as not to expose the actual values of the integer variable denoting the status of shell escape.

```latex
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \ShellEscapeURN #1 #2 #3
 {
  \sys_if_shell_unrestricted:TF
   { #1 } % unrestricted shell
   {
    \sys_if_shell_restricted:TF
     { #2 }
     { #3 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```