# Conditionally execute a command if a specific package is loaded

Tags: packages, conditionals

I am loading the `gitver` package based on the `expl3` solution accepted for my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508919/how-to-conditionally-load-a-package-only-if-shell-escape-write18-is-passed/508935#508935).

However, I need to use some commands depending on whether the package has actually been loaded. For instance, using a combination of `hyperxmp`, `hyperref` and `gitver`, one can provide an option `pdfversionid = \gitVer` to the `hypersetup` command (see code below).

The question is, how do I conditionally detect the presence of a package loaded (`gitver` in my example) and set up this conditional compilation?

Minimal conceptual example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\csname sys_if_shell_unrestricted:T\endcsname{\usepackage{gitver}}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage{hyperref}


% this commented paragraph is conceptual & needs fixing through a solution from this forum
% \hypersetup{%
% pdfversionid = {detect if gitver has been loaded & set to \gitVer if so; otherwise set to empty {}}
% }%

\begin{document}
Hello world!

% The following again describes my intended requirements in words
% detect if gitver has been loaded & print \versionBox{} if so; otherwise print "gitver not loaded"

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you would just use `\@ifpackageloaded`, but the command is limited to the preamble. To use it in the document body you need `\ltx@ifpackageloaded` from the [`ltxcmds` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/ltxcmds?lang=en). Since the macro has an `@` in the name, you need to wrap it in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
%\csname sys_if_shell_unrestricted:T\endcsname{\usepackage{gitver}}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% this commented paragraph is conceptual & needs fixing through a solution from this forum
\@ifpackageloaded{gitver}{
  \hypersetup{pdfversionid = \gitVer}
}{
  \hypersetup{pdfversionid = {}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Hello world!

\meaning\gitVer
% The following again describes my intended requirements in words
% detect if gitver has been loaded & print \versionBox{} if so; otherwise print "gitver not loaded"
\makeatletter
\ltx@ifpackageloaded{gitver}{\versionBox{}}{gitver not loaded}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `\gitVer` and `\VersionBox` are defined by `gitver`, just add

```
\providecommand{\gitVer}{}
\providecommand{\VersionBox}[1]{gitver not loaded}
```

after the conditional loading.

This exploits the fact that `\providecommand` does nothing if the command is already defined.

Comment: thank you. It worked for me. However, I think the `ltxcmds` package is a bit more flexible, and hence I'd like to accept that answer. However, yours is a valid solution and I am upvoting this.

Comment: @Krishna I disagree about the flexibility and you're fill your document with extraneous bits of code.